# p-datatable rowStyleClass doesn't style every row

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm using `<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="rowStyler" etc>`, and the method in my component looks like this:

```
  newRowFormat(rowData, rowIndex) {
    return('newRow');
  }
```

And in the component CSS, that class newRow looks like this:

```
:host /deep/ .newRow {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

The result is that every other row of the table is being colored gold, when every row should have that class applied to it.  Long story, but I want the class applied to every single row, not every other row.

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution (at least for now) turned out to be to use the forbidden `!important` rule:

```
:host /deep/ .newRow {
  background-color: gold!important;
}
```

Don't really like it (or understand why it works), but it works.  Trying to override PrimeNG styles is requiring me to use `:host /deep/` as well as `!important` in this case.